# Azure DevOps variable empty between steps

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am trying to read a text file using bash in a AZDO pipeline template, but for some reason the variable containing the name of the file is empty:

```
##deploy-to-env.yml

parameters:
  - name: env
    type: string
    default: ""

  - name: envLong
    type: string
    default: ""

stages:
  - stage: "deployTo${{ parameters.envLong }}"
    displayName: "Deploy to ${{ parameters.env }}"
    variables:
      - name: releasesFile
        value: ""
    jobs:
      - deployment:
        environment: "${{ parameters.env }}"
        displayName: "Deploy to ${{ parameters.env }}"
        strategy:
          runOnce:
            deploy:
              steps:
                - task: Bash@3
                  name: FindReleaseFile
                  displayName: "Find the releases.txt file"
                  inputs:
                    targetType: 'inline'
                    script: |
                      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=releasesFile;isOutput=true]$(find $(Build.SourcesDirectory) -name releases.txt -maxdepth 1 -type f 2>/dev/null)"

                - task: Bash@3
                  name: DownloadUsingArtifactTool
                  displayName: "Download Using Artifact Tool"
                  inputs:
                    targetType: 'inline'
                    script: |
                      echo "$(FindReleaseFile.releasesFile)"
```

The pipeline looks like this:

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - azure-pipelines
  paths:
    include:
      - "releases.txt"

stages:
  - template: deploy-to-env.yml
    parameters:
      env: "tst"
      envLong: "Test"
```

How can I pass the `releasesFile` variable to the 2nd task in `deploy-to-env.yml` template?

Comment: Have you tried `echo "$(releasesFile)"` and are you sure the `find` command finds anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the the repository was not cloned, adding `checkout: self` in the steps fixed it

Comment: A deployment job doesn't automatically clone the source repo. So you need to checkout the source repo within your job with `checkout: self`.